# Adding a logo to a panel on an app in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I add a logo to a panel on an app  in Google Earth Engine?

I don't even know how to upload a JPG or PNG to an asset and then add that image to the UI. Panel that I have on the right. Similar to the image below.

[image]

Comment: I don't think GFW is made as an EE app. Is probably made in App Engine with some backend/frontend framework

Answer (score 6):

To add a logo to a panel on GEE, you can upload it to your asset or host it externally.

**Option 1: Hosting an image externally and add as `ui.Chart()`**

This option will create an ugly blue border around your logo.

1. Upload your image to any website which allows direct html retrieval of your image. HTML retrieval is important. Without it this option will not work. Popular services like Google Drive, Google Photos will not work. Github works.
2. Obtain the link for your image (this should end with .jpg or .png). When you click on this link, the only thing visible must be your image.
3. Add this chunk to your code editor after replacing earth engine logo link with your logo's link.

   ```
   var table = ui.Chart(
   [
     ['<h2>Test Title</h2>'],
     ['<img src=https://earthengine.google.com/static/images/earth-engine- 
       logo.png width=150px>']
   ],
   'Table', {allowHtml: true});


   var titlePanel = ui.Panel([table], 'flow', {width: '300px', padding: '8px'});
   ui.root.insert(0, titlePanel);
   ```

   Example of this working can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/ba10572e3e02e691d9902e7ebe3b158c). Full credit goes to Ujaval Gandhi for this solution posted on the [GEE Developers Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/html$20image%7Csort:date/google-earth-engine-developers/GZRY2HOU8Rw/PVZjtvxzGgAJ).

**Option 2: Uploading to your GEE Asset**

This option will let you add the logo exactly like you want it (without any ugly borders) but needs more work.

1. Convert your logo to geotiff format. Use `gdal` on python, or any software like qgis to do that. The coordinate reference system can be anything. You need not worry about that. This step is necessary because GEE Assets do not accept jpgs or pngs at the moment.
2. Upload your logo in geotiff format as an asset in GEE by clicking on `Assets >> New >> GeoTiff

   [image]
3. Now open the code for your app and insert the following chunk:

   ```
   var logo = ee.Image('users/<your_username>/<AssetID_for_logo>').visualize({
       bands:  ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
       min: 0,
       max: 255
       });
   var thumb = ui.Thumbnail({
       image: logo,
       params: {
           dimensions: '642x291',
           format: 'png'
           },
       style: {height: '127px', width: '280px',padding :'0'}
       });
   var toolPanel = ui.Panel(thumb, 'flow', {width: '300px'});
   ui.root.widgets().add(toolPanel);
   ```

Example of this working can be found [here](https://kkraoj.users.earthengine.app/view/wildfire-danger).

Comment: any way to change the background to white and remove all the borders, with the first solution??

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible.

Comment: With recent changes, only images hosted on gstatic.com (owned by Google) or images converted as inline data:/ urls is allowed. To use the ui.Chart() method, you can convert your image as a Data URI and use it. Use an online converter such as https://onlinepngtools.com/convert-png-to-data-uri . The complete example is at https://code.earthengine.google.com/c110615d25584b64b46d88ac849a64b0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, @Rodrige E. Principe is right, GFW is not solely within the GEE environment. Global Forest Change Explorer is the one that is, and that one does not have a logo. However, I recently saw this post on the GEE Developer Google Group, about inserting logos into GEE apps. See the link to the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-earth-engine-developers/GZRY2HOU8Rw/kTbHnCJpBwAJ) and [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/38d7926656d15a7203efe6917108ccfc) embed.