# Link ui.Thumbnail to external URL in Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, url, user-interface

I figured out how to import logos into Earth Engine by following the link below..

[Adding a logo to a panel on an app in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331842/adding-a-logo-to-a-panel-on-an-app-in-google-earth-engine)

I would now like to code the logo such that when it is clicked, it will open a new tab from the link provided. I believe this should be possible because `onClick` functions can be written for the thumbnail.

I have put together the following code...

```
// DEFINE MAIN APP PANEL
var main = ui.Panel({style: {width: '310px', padding: '8px'}});

// IMPORT LOGO
var logo = ee.Image("users/SE_FHM/Logos/Tall_Timbers_Logo")

// DEFINE WEB LINK FOR THUMBNAIL
var link = ui.Label('Tall Timbers Research Station', {},'https://www.talltimbers.org');

// CONVERT TO THUMBNAIL, INSERT ON CLICK FUNCTION TO OPEN UP THE WEB LINK
var branding = ui.Thumbnail({image:logo,params:{bands:['b1','b2','b3'],min:0,max:255},style:{width:'270px',height:'123px'}});

// ADD TO THE MAP
main.add(branding);
main.add(link)
ui.root.insert(0, main);
```

[Link to full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/42fda69e708c9c8ab2d6e4e043ce0c43)

Are there any easy solutions to achieve this?